# Calling a URL using multithreading

Tags: java, php, multithreading

I have a PHP program which reads records sequentially from a MySQL database table, sends a message to a URL, and then updates the table using information from the response.

However, doing this serially, one row at a time, is very slow. Is there some way I can use multithreading in my code (PHP or Java) to send multiple messages at a time and update the table more quickly?

Comment: [php:pthreads](http://php.net/manual/de/book.pthreads.php) yes, it is possible. but I don't really understand what exactly you are trying to do

Comment: Basically what i need is a some examples where in i can call URL with POST data but using multithreading

Comment: still not clarifying the whole situation by one bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your issue, I think the best solution to call multi URL in multi thread is using cURL. Check this for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php
Feel free to ask me if you cannot apply it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,but my issue is i am trying to post multiple data with each instance of thread and each instance will give me response ,how do i handle/read each response

Comment: Yup, the cURL multi thread do exactly the thing you need. It allow you make request in bulk and get response for each request. Take a look in the link I sent to you, you will find down some helpful snipe code.